# Adding multiple exclusion paths in CGMutablePath

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, calayer

I was following the [winding rules documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH206-BAJIJJGD) provided for `fillRule` property which is used for trying to identify rather a point lies inside the region or not. 
My problem is trying to add multiple path exclusions in a path as below. I was trying to debug this in playground but couldn't identify how it is working and what was needed to achieve the result. The problem arises when i add more than one arc in a same line.

The results are funny:

[image]
[image]

```
    let maskView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    view.addSubview(maskView)
    maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
    //
    let path = CGMutablePath()

    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20),
                radius: 10,
                startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi,
                clockwise: false)

    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 220, y: 20),
                radius: 10,
                startAngle:  0, endAngle: 2 * .pi,
                clockwise: false)

    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300),
                radius: 12,
                startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi,
                clockwise: false)


    path.addRect(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size))




    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    maskLayer.path = path
    maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
    maskView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

The code provided by Apple does this very easily here:
[Flower pattern](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer)

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe what you really want to achieve. I assume you want to have a rectangle with three circular holes.

The main thing to understand is that a path can consist of several *subpaths*. Each subpath can either be *closed* (it ends where it started) or *open* (it ends at a different point than it started). Within a subpath, all line segments are connected.

What your trying to achieve requires several closed subpaths. Otherwise you cannot get the disconnected shapes.

In one of your examples it is obvious that the three circles have been automatically connected by lines, resulting in a trinagle. The [documation of `addArc`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgmutablepath/2427140-addarc) mentions this:

> If the path already contains a subpath, this method adds a line
>   connecting the current point to the starting point of the arc.

In order to create a new subpath, either *move* to the start of the next subpath (using `move`) or *close* the previous one (using `closeSubpath`). So the middle part of your code should look like so:

```
let path = CGMutablePath()

path.addRect(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size))
path.closeSubpath

path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20),
            radius: 10,
            startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi,
            clockwise: false)
path.closeSubpath

path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 220, y: 20),
            radius: 10,
            startAngle:  0, endAngle: 2 * .pi,
            clockwise: false)
path.closeSubpath

path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300),
            radius: 12,
            startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi,
            clockwise: false)
path.closeSubpath
```

Comment: Hi @Codo, Thanks for the clue that we need to close the subpaths and also notice the addArc method connects the start and end. But I see it same as before, although you mentioned it to `move` which is what exactly made it working.. Thanks. :D Please add move to center for the next arc to mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you set up only one path. However, in order to see the `fillRule` in effect, you would need multiple sub paths.
Try to do the following:

- Create a rectangular path (your screen bounds).
- Create your exclusion paths and add them as sub paths to the rectangle (via `CGMutablePath.addPath`).
- Use the path in your `maskLayer`

See the following playground code for a working example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MaskView: UIView {
    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }

    var highlightedAreas = [CGPath]() {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    func setMaskColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        (layer as? CAShapeLayer)?.fillColor = color.cgColor
        (layer as? CAShapeLayer)?.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        frame = superview?.bounds ?? .zero
        let path = makePath()
        (layer as? CAShapeLayer)?.path = path
    }

    private func makePath() -> CGPath {
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.addRect(bounds)

        for subPath in highlightedAreas {
            path.addPath(subPath)
        }

        return path
    }
}

class DemoViewController: UIViewController {
    private var mask: MaskView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mask = MaskView()
        mask.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(mask)

        mask.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        mask.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        mask.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        mask.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        view.backgroundColor = .green

        let path1 = CGMutablePath()
        path1.addRect(CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 120, height: 80))

        let path2 = CGMutablePath()
        path2.addRect(CGRect(x: 150, y: 110, width: 80, height: 120))

        mask.highlightedAreas = [path1, path2]

        mask.setMaskColor(UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7))
    }
}

let demoController = DemoViewController()

demoController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = demoController
```

It results in a view that looks like this:

[image]

The view background is green. The dark color is the fill color of the path.
The path consists of a large rectangle the size of the view and 2 rectangular, overlapping sub paths. Where there is one sub path overlapping, the path will not be filled (even-odd fill rule, 2 paths overlap). However, the area where the path and the two sub paths overlap the fill color is visible (3 path overlap).